# Start In folder where is it used?

Tags: c++, windows, vb.net, shortcut-file

The Start In folder on a shortcut is one of those things I've never quite understood

Yes I can understand what it is intended for but I have never quite worked/found out where it 'touches' an application

If I create a shortcut to CMD.exe and set a Start In folder in that shortcut and then type Set at the command prompt it does not appear in any variable so i'm not quite sure when/if any application actually gets this information but it obviously has a purpose

Can anyone give me an example in VB or C++ on how an application "sees" the Start In folder

Comment: Doesn't the CMD prompt show you the directory you set? The directory you set in the shortcut is what becomes the working directory of the program. In C or C++ you can get it with the [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) function.

Comment: The start in folder (also known as the current working directory) is that place that your program will start looking when given a relative path to a file. E.g. `std::ifstream file; file.open("fred")` looks for the file `fred` in the current working directory.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Do you know if SafeDllSearchMode or any other registry entry affects the way/order file.open etc searches the relative paths  to find the file ? Thanks